# How to add ajax/no refresh to phpmailer contact form

Tags: javascript, php

I know similar / same question is asked many time but after spending whole day without success I have to ask for help. I have a PHPMailer contact form which works fine and submits messages without problem. After sending message I get message sent alert in a new page. I'd like it to stay on the contact page and get the message sent alert in the contact form div. I tried almost all the examples I found but nothing worked for me. My JS knowledge is a little less than non-existent so please give specific instructions. I assume HTML/CSS is not the problem since the form works so here is the php and js code.
PHP

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

function Filter($Value){
    $Step1  =   trim($Value);
    $Step2  =   strip_tags($Step1);
    $Step3  =   htmlspecialchars($Step2, ENT_QUOTES);
        return $Step3;
}

$Name                   =   Filter($_POST["name"]);
$Phone                  =   Filter($_POST["phone"]);
$Email                  =   Filter($_POST["email"]);
$Message                =   Filter($_POST["message"]);

$Mail                   =   new PHPMailer(true);
try{
    $Mail->SMTPDebug            =   0;
    $Mail->isSMTP();
    $Mail->Host                 =   'mail.xxx.com';
    $Mail->SMTPAuth             =   true;
    $Mail->CharSet              =   'UTF-8';
    $Mail->Username             =   xxx@xxx.com';
    $Mail->Password             =   xxxxxxxxxxx;
    $Mail->SMTPSecure           =   'tls';
    $Mail->Port                 =   587;
    $Mail->SMTPOptions          =   array(
                                            'ssl' => [
                                                'verify_peer' => false,
                                                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                                'allow_self_signed' => true
                                            ],
                                        );
    $Mail->setFrom(xxx@xxx.com', $Name);
    $Mail->addAddress('info@xxx.com');
    $Mail->addReplyTo($Email, $Name);
    $Mail->isHTML(true);
    $Mail->MsgHTML($Message);

    $Mail->send();
    echo 'Message Sent';
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error! : ', $Mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
   $('#contact-form').validator();
   /* Contact Form */
   $("#contact-Form").validator().on("submit", function(event) {
       if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
           // handle the invalid form...
           formError();
           submitMSG(false, "Error!");
       } else {
           // everything looks good!
           event.preventDefault();
           submitForm();
       }
   });
   function submitForm() {
       // initiate variables with form content
       var name = $("#name").val();
       var email = $("#email").val();
       var message = $("#message").val();
       var terms = $("#terms").val();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../php/contact.php",
           data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&terms=" + terms, 
           success: function(text) {
               if (text == "success") {
                   formSuccess();
               } else {
                   formError();
                   submitMSG(false, text);
               }
           }
       });
   }

   function formSuccess() {
       $("#contact-Form")[0].reset();
       submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!");
       $("input").removeClass('notEmpty'); // resets the field label after submission
       $("textarea").removeClass('notEmpty'); // resets the field label after submission
   }
   function formError() {
       $("#contact-Form").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
           $(this).removeClass();
       });
   }
   function submitMSG(valid, msg) {
       if (valid) {
           var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated";
       } else {
           var msgClasses = "h3 text-center";
       }
       $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
   }
});
```

UPDATE: I removed both contact.js and validator.js. Contact form is working exactly the same. Messages going thru and I get contact.php page with !Message sent! alert. So JS code wasn't doing anything anyway. I'd appreciate if you could guide from here. What do I need to add and where.

Comment: what is `..validator()`? A plugin? If your issue is page getting refreshing after the submit I guess the issue is in `$("#contact-Form").validator().on("submit", function(event) {`

Comment: it is another js script (https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) I left it as it is in the contact form template I used. Script is stored locally and I've set path in html to load it. The page doesn't refresh but it redirects to contact.php and displays 'Message sent'

Comment: assign return value of `$('#contact-form').validator();` to a new variable and call `.on("submit", function(event)` from that. i.e: `let x = $('#contact-form').validator(); x.on("submit", function(event) {` without creating two validator instances